# python program to tell the number of words in code without length function?the error is unexpected .plzz tell where i am wrong

Tags: python, list, if-statement

i've been trying this code from 1 hour and its output coming out is really unexpected.

```
var=input('sentence')
no=1
for i in var:
  if i==" ": #i've added a space as the number of words will be the number of spaces in a sentence
    no+=1
print(no)
```

Comment: What's your expected output? What's the error you are getting?

Comment: there is a syntax error in your `if i==" "` you have to add `:` at the end of it like `if i==" ":`

Comment: I wanted to know the number of words in the program but the output is like:  1,1,2,2,2,3 ,3,3,4,4,4 rather than 4

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the : at the end of your if statement. The following should work:

```
var=input('sentence')
no=1
for i in var:
  if i==" ":
    no+=1
print(no)
```